# EntityLoad dates in future

Tags: coldfusion

I have a table with events. 
I'm trying to display a list of all the events in the future.
I'm using orm but I can't figure out for the life of me how to select dates in the future.
The filters only accept "=" and not ">".
I currently have this but it obviously doesn't work:

```
var events = entityLoad("tbl_events",{"eventActive" = 1, "eventDate" > NOW()},"EventDate Asc",{maxResults = count});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use HQL

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSf0ed2a6d7fb07688310730d81223d0356fc-7ffe.html

```
var events = ormExecuteQuery(from tbl_events where eventActive = 1 AND eventDate > ?, [now()]);
```

Comment: That fixed it thanks. 


ormExecuteQuery("from tbl_events where eventActive = 1 AND eventDate > ? ORDER BY eventDate ASC", [lsDateFormat(now(),'yyyy-mm-dd')]);